# Keras CNN Hidden Dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm looking at Keras' example for convolutional neural networks. (See https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py for example.) However, I cannot figure out what the "hidden_dims" parameter means. I know it stands for hidden dimensions, but what are hidden dimensions, and how do they differ from hidden layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you linked to, you have

```
hidden_dims = 250
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
```

Hence, `hidden_dims` is the number of neurons in this hidden layer.
For example, the number of neurons in the first hidden layer of the network below is 4:

[image]